# VC++ fatal error LNK1104 w/ d3d9x.lib

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, directx

So I'm trying to compile a DX9 program that include the headers d3d9.h and d3dx9.h. However it keeps getting a fatal error trying to find d3dx9.lib. What's interesting is that when I try to input d3dx9.h it shows up as in "Microsoft SDKs\Windows..." and in "Microsoft DirectX SDK...". I have set up the include and library directories under VC++ Directories for the project. I get no errors in the code, but only when compiling. DirectX (June 2010) did install correctly, so I'm not sure what could be causing this, any help?

Comment: What is it?  d3d9x.lib or d3dx9.lib?  Copy and paste error messages.  And if you changed settings then say *exactly* what you changed.

Comment: 1>Build started 4/21/2012 11:19:26 AM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\Direct3D.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  main.cpp
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'd3d9x.lib'
1>
1>Build FAILED.

Comment: was the exact output from compiling. And it is all set as d3dx9.lib. I have set $(DXSDK_DIR)include under include and $(DXSDK_DIR)lib\x86 under library. The weird part is that the tutorial (http://www.directxtutorial.com/Tutorial9/B-Direct3DBasics/dx9B5.aspx#still) does not say to add those to the build path.

Answer (score 1):

There is no d3d9x.lib, you probably transposed the letters.  It is d3dx9.lib.  Check your linker settings for the name, maybe a #pragma comment in your code.

If you are sure you got it right then use the Linker, Input, Ignore Specific Library setting.

Comment: Wow, I swear I looked at it for 3 hours and thought I typed it right. I owe you one.